# show badge number only if figure is more than 0

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic and angularjs project. In one of the tabs in display a badge that contains a number and i want the badge to appear only if the figure is more than 0.

```
<ion-tab icon="ion-android-notifications" title="Notifications" href="#/tab/notifications" ng-app="starter" ng-controller="notifications_count" badge="total" badge-style="badge-assertive">
       <ion-nav-view name="list-notifications"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
```

Comment: try ng-if  condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ion-tab icon="ion-android-notifications" title="Notifications" href="#/tab/notifications" ng-app="starter" ng-controller="notifications_count" badge="total" ng-if="total>0" badge-style="badge-assertive">
   <ion-nav-view name="list-notifications"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```